# mongoose $geoNear, $near, and $nearSphere are not allowed in this context

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my Schema:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    coordinates: {
        type: { type: String },
        coordinates: [],
       },
})
```

and then I add this:

```
userSchema.index({ coordinates: "2dsphere" });
```

I want to find all coordinates within a radius. This is the method I am calling:

```
router.post('/users/query', async(req,res)=>{
    var pageOptions = {
        page: req.body.page || 0,
        limit:  10
    }
    const query ={     location: {
        $near: {
         $maxDistance: req.body.searchQuery.maxDistance,
         $geometry: {
          type: "Point",
          coordinates: req.body.searchQuery.coordinates
         }
        }
       }} 
       console.log(query)
    User.find(query)
    .skip(pageOptions.page*pageOptions.limit)
    .limit(pageOptions.limit)
    .exec(function (error, users) {
        if(error) { res.status(500).json({error}); return; };
        User.countDocuments(query).exec((error,total)=>{
            if(error) { 
                res.status(500).json({error})
            }else{
                res.status(200).json({users,total});

             };
        })
    })
})
```

I did it like in this articel: https://medium.com/@galford151/mongoose-geospatial-queries-with-near-59800b79c0f6

But I get error $geoNear, $near, and $nearSphere are not allowed in this context. somebody knows why?

This is my searchQuery:

```
{ searchQuery: 
{ coordinates: [ 9.993681899999956, 53.5510846 ],
maxDistance: 1000 } }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the count method instead of the countDocuments method

Comment: This isn't a very good answer. `.count()` is deprecated and `.countDocuments()` should be used. For a proper solution, check the bug report on the MongoDB forums for this exact issue --> https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1834

Answer (score 0):

The collection has to be indexed by the coordinates as type 2dsphere